# Deserializing 2d array in kotlinx.serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, multidimensional-array, serialization

I am quite new to Kotlin but and I have successfully used Kotlin serialization on many cases - works out of the box even for nested classes, mutableLists etc. However I struggle with two dimensional arrays.

My class:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*

@Serializable
data class Thing(val name:String)

@Serializable
data class Array2D(val width:Int, val height:Int,
                   var arrayContents:Array<Array<Thing?>> = Array(1){Array(1){null} }){
    init{
        arrayContents = Array(width){Array(height){null} }
    }
}
```

And when doing this:

```
val a = Array2D(2, 2)
a.arrayContents[0][0] = Thing("T0")
a.arrayContents[0][1] = Thing("T1")
a.arrayContents[1][0] = Thing("T2")
a.arrayContents[1][1] = Thing("T3")

val json = Json {
   allowStructuredMapKeys = true
}

val jsonString = json.encodeToString(Array2D.serializer(), a)
assertEquals(
    """
    {"width":2,"height":2,"arrayContents":[[{"name":"T0"},{"name":"T1"}],[{"name":"T2"},{"name":"T3"}]]}
    """.trim(),
    jsonString
) // encoding is OK

val b = json.decodeFromString(deserializer = Array2D.serializer(), jsonString) 
// this fails to reproduce "a" and stops at first array level
// b.arrayContents = {Thing[2][]} (array of nulls) instead of {Thing[2][2]} (array of array of Thing)
```

If it can encode the class to String it should decode it as well, right? Or am I missing something here? Maybe I should use custom serializer but there are not many examples that fit my case. One example is https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/357 but it is only one level of array.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization/deserialization for arrays (including multi-dimensional) works out of the box.
Unexpected behavior is related to `init` section of your data class. It's executed after deserialization happens and overwrites data parsed from JSON.

It also happens when you create instance of `Array2D` manually:

```kotlin
val x = Array2D(1, 1, Array(1) { Array(1) { Thing("0") } })
println(x.arrayContents[0][0]) //will print null
```

You just need to replace `init` block with secondary constructor (default value for `arrayContents` is redundant, by the way), and you may declare `arrayContents` as `val` now:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Array2D(val width: Int, val height: Int, val arrayContents: Array<Array<Thing?>>) {
    constructor(width: Int, height: Int) : this(width, height, Array(width) { Array(height) { null } })
}
```

Comment: This fixed it - made the same mistake in a few places. Thank you for help! I had problems with putting the default value in the primary constructor with parameters - hence the ugly workaround with init{}. Now its both clean & working :)